# How to post a ViewModel from a list of ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel, model-binding

I currently have a view that I pass a list of ViewModels to. I would then like to select one of those ViewModels and post it back to my controller. I currently have a foreach loop going through each ViewModel and displaying their data. With each ViewModel, there is also a submit button, but it doesn't seem to be working as I hoped.

Code as explained (View):

```
@model IEnumerable<RoboticsScheduler.Models.UserVM>
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserApproved", "Approve"))
{
...
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    ...
    @*Modified model data*@
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Approve User" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    }
}
```

Then in my accepting controller I have UserVM as a parameter, but I keep getting empty UserVM's in the controller.

Code in Controller:

```
public async Tas<ActionResult> UserApproved(UserVM uvm)
{
...
}
```

If anyone has suggestions for how I could accomplish something like this, that would be great!

**Edit**

Showing more in depth of the view plus moved the BeginForm into loop:

```
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Approved", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.EmailConfirmed.ToString()
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="col-md-10">
                    @{List<string> roles = ViewBag.Roles;
                    int i = 0;
                    }
                    @foreach (string role in roles)
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Roles[i])
                        @Html.Label(role, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        <br />
                    }
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Approve User" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `UserVM`?

Comment: Also, ViewModels are not Models - don't use Entity Framework entity classes as ViewModels - which is what this looks like.

Comment: What do you mean by what is the definition? It contains various attributes which are displayed and/or edited in the view.

Comment: If you only want to post a single UserVM, you'll need to move the `BeginForm` into the for loop.

Comment: Your need to show the view - how are you generating the controls for each `UserVM`? If its not binding its because your view is wrong

Comment: The view works fine, each UserVM displays fine, but they aren't posting. I agree their is something wrong with the view because of this though.

Comment: Also, I moved the BeginForm into the loop and I get the same results.

Comment: The view is NOT fine. And unless you have created the html manually without any html helpers a `foreach` loop cannot possible generate the correct `name` attributes. You need to show the view.

Comment: I didn't say the view is fine... I said it's displaying fine. In my last comment I said "I agree their is something wrong with the view...". Would you like to see the entire view? I thought I posted the important parts that would make a difference.

Comment: @Jon, The only important part is how you generate the controls (only need to see them for one or two properties of the model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke let me know if my edit helps

Comment: Yes, But the answer depends on what you really want to do here. Your generating controls for every item in the collection inside one form which suggests you actually want to post back the whole collection. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the user would modify one of the items then select the submit button for that item. Then that item would post back.

Comment: That really makes no sense. If you want to do that then why would you have textboxes etc for all the other items (very confusing UI). The correct approach in that case would be to have a readonly display of the collection, with each object having a link to an edit page

Comment: And if you inspect the html your currently generating, it will have controls such as `<input type="text" name="item.Email" ../>` which have no relationship at all to you model (your model does not have a property name `item`)

Comment: Their are no textboxes. The editorfor is for a list of bools where the user selects specific roles for the item. The reason I don't want to have a dedicated edit view is because their is not much editing to be done. All the user needs to do is select certain roles from the checkboxes (editorfor) and submit that item.

Comment: item is one of the ViewModels in the list of viewmodels. This is created in the declaration of the loop.

Comment: Make no difference - look at the html generated for the hidden input and the radio buttons. They have name attributes that have no relationship to your model therefore will never bind to your model when you post.

Comment: item.email is in a displayfor. Isn't displayfor read-only? which would not make it an input?

Comment: Which is where my question derives. Is there anyway to bind when I post?

Comment: No as it is. Your model in the view is a collection so your parameter in the post method needs to match. But if you only want to edit one item, then you view should be for one item, not a collection

Comment: Sounds good, I wasn't sure if their was anyway to do this.

Comment: I have a solution. But first let me know if your are able to hit the controller action when you click on submit button

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to understand how MVC binds values back to controller when a form is posted. To explain in detail..

**Solution:**
Your view model is `@model IEnumerable<RoboticsScheduler.Models.UserVM>` and Hence the form submit becomes tricky since you are **Not** dealing with a single object. You have got the for loop correct, But you need to understand whats happening with it.

```
@foreach (string role in roles)
 {
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Roles[i])
    @Html.Label(role, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <br />
 }
```

Here the editor for renders a HTML tag with a name something like `item.Role` this is the problem here. The name parameter is the only thing that you need to get right for your form post to be successful. So all you have to do is...

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Roles[i], new {Name = 'RoleType'})
```

here I am implicitly giving a name to the input tag. Also I assume your ViewModel UserVM has a property named RoleType. something like below

```
public class UserVM
{
  public string RoleType {get;set;}
  public int UserId {get;set;} // you will see why this in my below explanation
}
```

Now when you submit the form MVC will see whats the input parameter type of the controller action, its UserVM object, Now it looks inside this object to find a property with the same name as the input elements inside the form. In our case we have a input tag with name RoleType also we have a property with the name RoleType inside the object, So MVC is happy to bind he value.

**Suggestions:**
After Reading your comments I understood that you want to show a dropdown of roles from which the user wants to select a role. So you can try this..

change the logic of the way you are extracting data from the Viewbag

```
@{
   List<string> roles = ViewBag.Roles;
   int i = 0;
   var RolesList = roles.select(c => new SelectListItem {Text=c,Value=c}).ToList();
 }
```

The above code will build a list of SelectListItem objects (Which is the one we must use in MVC when dealing with dropdowns) using Linq syntax. Now inside
your Form change to this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Approved", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id, new {Name = "UserId"}) 
        @Html.DropDownList("RoleType",RolesList)
        @Html.Label(role, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <br />
    }
   }
```

So the above syntax says its a dropdown and also has a name **RoleType** to it, Also there is a hidden field with the name changed to **UserId** (as we know why in my explanation above). Which will now get posted when the form is submitted. You can put any other fields in the hiddenfor syntax if you want them to be posted as well.

**NOTE:** The main thing one should know when playing with MVC is that the default **MVC Model Binding** is purely dependent on the **Name** attribute of the input tags (also select tag) to achieve a successful post.

**Additional Info:** The above form post is equal to doing the same in the query string as this..

```
yourlocalhost/Approved/Index?RoleType="Admin"&UserId="23"
```

You can still have the same controller syntax. This is to make you more clear on the model binding done by MVC. You can try it and inspect your object in the action method to see the values being populated to the respective properties of the object.

Comment: This is anti-MVC and will create all sorts of problems. It wont give true 2-way model binding, It will fail if the view needs to be returned, client side validation will not be possible, its creating invalid html etc. (and `new { name = "UserId" }` will not change the name attribute so it wont bind anyway)

Comment: Not sure what you mean in this statement`It will fail if the view needs to be returned`, Validation I do agree. It is possible only with EditorFor along with data anootations. But I do not agree with the fact `new { name = "UserId" }` will not work as I have got it working in most of my cases. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Also I refuse to accept that this is anti MVC because all I have been doing is changing the name attribute, which is just fine according to me. OK here's a scenario. We can always write a pure HTML syntax inside our razor view right? And we can get it working exactly the same as the @Html.EditorFor.. (Ultimately the rendered DOM is Pure HTML). So changing the name attribute or writing a pure HTML its all the same. All depends on the developers comfort zone.

Comment: Your posting one object to the controller, but if the view needs to be returned (say because of a server side validation error) then it will fail because the view expects a collection (it will throw an exception)

Comment: Try it! It will not change the name attribute (inspect the source code to understand why). There is a workaround to do it (and you have almost got it)  but too dangerous in the hands of beginners who don't understand the inner workings of MVC and model binding.

Comment: You have a point there. This will be a problem only if he requires validation in his view. But all I see is a one dropdown. But you made a good point, Further discussing, The user wants to post only a single object to controller, But display a list of form in the UI. There is always a solution. Either he can make the form submit by ajax which will solve your above mentioned issue (he would require to move the form logic into a new partial view page). OR redirect to Index method with validation sate when ever there is a validation error (Which will again come back to same page with errors).

Comment: Not sure brother. I will anyways try it and share the Screenshots with you (as I know it works). But I would require your email Id to share the ScreenShots. if you can update your profile with a email id I cab grab it from there...

Comment: Since you are so confident that it will not work. I want to give it a try

Comment: Its capital N `{ new Name = UserId }` :) But it should never be used

Comment: updated my answer with Capital N. Excuse me for the syntax, I am just typing it here in the SO, VS intellisense effect

Comment: And did you mean  `anti-MVC` for my QueryString thing?? If yes then this was just a additional info so that he understands that the object property names are the real players..

Answer (score 0):

```
//Person
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";    
 }

<h2>Person</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { id = "Id"})
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { id = "Name" })
    </div>

     if (Model != null && Model.Phone != null)
     {
         foreach (var phone in Model.Phone)
         {
             Html.RenderPartial("_Phone", phone);
         }
     }    

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}


//phone
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Phone

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Phone"))
{
     <div>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Use Html.BeginCollectionItem
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/